# Kotlin: обработка иных значений в лямбда-выражениях

Tags: kotlin, lambda

У меня есть userDto, содержащий `programs`, которые содержат поле `actual`. Актуальная программа может быть только одна. Мне нужно получить такую программу. Я выполняю следующее:

```
userDto.programs.sortedBy { it.created }.findLast { it.actual }?
```

Окей, но мне хочется предусмотреть случай, когда программы вообще не окажется и `findLast` вернёт null, и выбросить, к примеру, исключение. Подскажите, как лучше дописать выражение, чтобы это сделать?

Comment: [`last`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/last.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хотите выбросить свое исключение то дописать можно так

```
userDto.programs.sortedBy { it.created }.findLast { it.actual } ?: throw MyOwnException("Somthing wrong!")
```

Если использовать функцию `last` вместо `findLast`, то функция выбросит `NoSuchElementException` если не обнаружит элемента по заданному критерию. Тогда Вам нужно обернуть вызов в `try\catch` и обработать исключение.